# How to Validate text box in spring mvc to enter only digit?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am creating registration form in spring MVC. There is one Contact number field i bind it with long field value in bean. i want to validate it to enter only digit. i want annotation base validation in spring MVC. any help will be appreciated. I am new in Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Spring Validations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/validation.html).[Here](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-validation-1.html) is one nice tutorial for implementing it.In your case you need to implement your own validation logic using in **Custom-Validator** .Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273329/apply-custom-validator-in-spring-mvc-controller-in-more-than-one-class) link for some help regarding implementing custom validations.

Answer (score 0):

Spring supports standard JSR-303 Bean validation out of the box. Just follow the very well documented use case within the [Spring Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation)